# Did Goten and Trunks ever fused using the Potara earrings?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

We've seen Goten and Trunks fusing several times using the metamor fusion. But have they ever fused using the Potara earrings? How about in Dragon Ball Heroes? If so, what's the name of the warrior when fusing using Potaras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer would be no.** There isn't any Potara based fusion between the two characters eve in Dragon Ball Heroes.

- There is the [Adult Xeno: Gotenks](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Gotenks:_Xeno).
- Atlhough this is far from canon, Goten and Trunks's EX-Fusion from *Dragon Ball Fusions* [EX Gotenks](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/EX_Gotenks), has a completely different taking after Trunks more than Goten.

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

There is no need for them to fuse with the Potara earrings since Goten is irrelevant to the franchise. Goten exist just for the purpose of Gotenks. That is all.